# Anywhere on Stack Exchange for this question?

Tags: discussion

Is there anywhere on Stack Exchange for this question I asked? https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78651/suggestions-on-what-database-to-use

(Also, should this be tagged as "support" and not as "discussion"?)

Answer (score 8):

Shopping recommendation questions are [generally off-topic on all StackExchange sites.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

[DBA.Stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) might be a good venue, if you can ask a question that *has a specific answer,* and is not merely a poll.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Ask it on dba with a slant towards actually defining what your database requirements are.

PS: I'm one of the mods on dba.SE, so I can promise you that a well-crafted question will be quite welcome there. But if you just say "databases are hard, let's go shopping" I'll close it in a heartbeat. ;)